# Docker compose unsupported option 'target'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am developing a nest js application and I need to deploy it to a remote server with ubuntu, i'm new with docker and everything is fine on windows 8 and ubuntu 22 i can use my app fine but on server i get this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRURh.png) error in the server

in using this docker files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGWvS.png) Dockerfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqKce.png) docker-compose

On my windows and ubuntu works docker-compose up dev and docker-compose up prod. It seems weird that it works on two different systems but not on the server, they all have the same version of docker and docker-compose

I try to change the version in the yml, but the error persists.

Comment: Please post your code and error messages as text in the question rather than linking to images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What are you expecting `target`  to do? Ideally, you use two separate Dockerfiles with different CMD, for example, for debugging and production . Then separate compose files for development. Then a real deployment file for Production, such as k8s manifest or Helm Chart (or remove Compose and use minikube)